# Execute MSSQL procedures in PowerShell and store the output

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

What I'd like to do is execute two stored procedures from a PowerShell and save the results into a log file.

I have two procedures so I though it would be easier to create one "master" procedure which will execute the two procedures.

So far I was able to execute the master procedure successfully (both child procedures ran), but only the output from the second is stored in the log file.

```
param([string]$datein="string")

$OutputFile = "C:\...\ScriptOutput.txt"

$handler = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInfoMessageEventHandler] {param($sender, $event) Out-File -filepath $OutputFile -inputobject $event.Message };

$SqlConnection = new-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("server=ServerName;database=DB;integrated security=true")
$SqlConnection.add_InfoMessage($handler); 
$SqlConnection.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = $true;
$SqlConnection.Open() | Out-Null

# Execute procedures
$cmd = new-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("[dbo].[tst_master]", $SqlConnection)
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'

$cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_in",$datein) | Out-Null

$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null

$SqlConnection.Close()
```

**EDIT:**

Its on virtual machine, Windows server 2016. Powershell version Major:5, Minor: 1. Im working with MSSQL 2014.

Comment: Take a look at the bcp command you should be able to do this using that and a simple commandline call.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189569(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you. But isnt the bcp command only for queries? Moreover, I need to catch the messages from those procedures, not any output table.

Comment: What OS? What version of SQL Server? What version of PowerShell?

Comment: Just added this info. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You should be able to use bcp to call a procedure as well. 
bcp "EXEC MyDB.MySchema.MyProc" queryout c:\my_export_filename.txt -c -t, -T -SServerName\InstanceName


Test in SSMS using EXEC xp_cmdshell 'bcp "EXEC MyDB.MySchema.MyProc" queryout c:\my_export_filename.txt -c -t, -T -SServerName\InstanceName'